# Inverse of $I-e^A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What's the inverse of $I-e^A$, where I is the identity matrix and A is a matrix?
A and $I-e^A$  are both invertible.
For simplicity's sake, the inverse of $-(A+\frac{A^2}{2!}+\frac{A^3}{3!})$ can be considered as an approximation.

Comment: $A$ needs to be invertible.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks for your reminder. I revised the question. A and $I-e^A$  are both invertible.

Comment: The eigenvalues of $I-e^A$ are $1-e^\lambda$ where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. (Hence, for example,  if $A= 2 \pi i I$, then $I-e^A = 0$.)

Comment: Do you expect to find an expression that is simpler than just $(I-\exp(A))^{-1}$ ?

Comment: @Wouter Yes! Does it exist ?

Comment: If $||e^{A}|| < 1$ then $(I - e^{A})^{-1} = \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} e^{kA} = I + e^{A} + e^{2A} + ...$. You may look up [Neumann series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series)

Comment: @AbhishekHalder: You need something like $\|e^A\| <1$ for that to make sense.

Comment: @copper.hat: true, edited.

Comment: @AbhishekHalder Thanks a lot. Where did you find this expression ?

Comment: Even for diagonal $A$, there is no better expression that $(I-e^A)^{-1}$.

Comment: @ David: See the link in my comment.

Comment: @AbhishekHalder Got it

Comment: @copper.hat The nature of the problem I am working on has guaranteed that  $||e^{A}|| < 1$, so AbhishekHalder's answer is perfect for me.

Comment: @David: That is information that is very relevant to the question and should be part of the question.

Comment: More precisely, the series converge iff $\rho(e^A)< 1$  iff for every $\lambda\in spectrum(A)$, $Re(\lambda)<0$..